# How i can see long layout in preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a long Screen, and i set ScrollView, but in Preview screen in Android Studio i do not see part of the Screen. How i can see it?[image]

Answer (score 36):

I found another & pretty cool solution. It's not about size of the layout in preview.
You can simulate scrolling instead, to see the hidden content.

Use with tools, as it has influence only in preview. Then increase/decrease value for "scroll".

```
<YourRootViewOfAnyType
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
...
tools:layout_marginTop="-200dp"
...
>

</YourRootViewOfAnyType>
```

Comment: nice hack for designing time .

Comment: This is awesome because it will update my screen in the design view and take me to any portion I want it and 'lock' it there, till I want.

Comment: This is awesome hack. thank you sir. What an Idea :)

Answer (score 17):

> Here's The Magic Solution :

[image]

Click on the highlighted button to increase the size of the preview window.
Note : You can increase the size to any desired size!

[image]

Then use the zoom button to zoom and see the preview.

[image]

Here's how it will look then.

[image]

To get the scroll Bar in application ....[image]

Use scroll view as the root view in your .xml file and then make the nesting of layouts.

If you don't want the scrolling image to fade away in app then add the code under ScrollView :

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Comment: quite original manner of solving an issue. Please shorten it in the future during answering a lot.. The suspense was killing me... to see the actual code trick was at the bottom ;-)

Comment: tnx. it was quick and simple.

Comment: Not useful for me because my mouse moves with more speed than I can control. Second things my view also start to stretch as I drag to resize. Thirdly whenever I update my layout, the screen resets to its original height. This one will always work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411306/787399.

Answer (score 10):

If you put your layouts in a ScrollView it should automatically (at least in Android Studio) show you everything.

Another workaround is to make a new AVD with a big resolution, something like 4000px height, and use that for preview, worked for me :)

Comment: how i can set AVD height?

Comment: You must create a new AVD definition. Open your AVD manager and select new device definition (something similar) and there you can define your own resolution.

Comment: i have them in a scrollview and it doesn't let me scroll.. that's one frustrating issue!

Answer (score 9):

Open the xml of the layout. In the preview pane press the 'Show Design + Blue print' button. This will show the design along side the blue print. Hover the mouse over the blue print, you'll then be able to scroll. The design beside it will scroll simultaneously.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Update your android studio now  you can see the preview while scrolling .

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio `4.1` you can easily increase height of preview by dragging the corresponding button:

[image: Expand preview size button]

Answer (score 5):

As Verdan answered, you should use a ScrollView.
But the trick is that the ScrollView must be your root layout (at least temporary).
So just wrap all your layout into a ScrollView (even though you have another nested one or a ListView).

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- PUT All YOUR STUFF HERE -->

</ScrollView>
```

Then you will see all your layout in the preview.
And when your are done you can just remove it

Comment: in my case i need to add LinearLayour (vertical) to make this work OR i cant resize the height of constraint layout. so the tree would be like this Scrollview -> LinearLayout -> ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 4):

Open Android Studio Design View
Click on the Blue Toggle Design or Blue Print Button
Select Design + Blue Print

Now hover on the blueprint view and when you scroll your design layout will also scroll automatically showing you the complete view.[image: See Example]